# How to capitalize only the first letter of a string, while lowercasing the rest?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My string is:

> 1  STATE OF GOA THROUGH CHIEF

I want the output to be like

> 1  State of goa through chief

How can I keep the first letter capital and convert other to small? I had used `.ToLower()`, but it converts all the letters to small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2Try this:

```
petitioner = respetMyReader["pet_name"].ToString();
petitioner = petitioner.Substring(2,1).ToUpper() + petitioner.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "1 STATE OF GOA THROUGH CHIEF";
bool sawLetter = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
foreach (char c in s) {
    if (!sawLetter && Char.IsLetter(c)) {
        sb.Append(Char.ToUpperInvariant(c));
        sawLetter = true;
    }
    else {
        sb.Append(Char.ToLowerInvariant(c));
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

You could get super fancy and write this as an aggregate query in LINQ but that would be a case of fancy coding syndrome. Just make this as an extension method and move on.

Note that this is at least an order of magnitude more maintainable than using `Substring` to split the string into two pieces.

Comment: This is a nice solution, and btw @Jason I guess you meant `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);`?

Comment: @CodeCanvas: Yes, thanks! (That's what I get for using the compiler in my head.)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this just before setting the value of HiddenValue4 to Fil_No...

```
String FinalString = fil_no.substring(1, 3) + LCase(fil_no.substring(4, (fil_no.Length - 4)));
```

This should keep the first three characters as whatever fil_no is and make all the others lowercase.